# @Property - Function doesn't get executed - Python

Tags: python, class, oop

I try set a property of class, but the dictionary is not being set. I've another code, where same code worked

```
class CB:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self._kst_mapping = None
        
    @property
    def kst_mapping(self):
        if self._kst_mapping is None:
            self.set_kst_mapping()
        return self._kst_mapping
    
    def  set_kst_mapping(self):
        kst_mapping = {
            'Test1': [4130,4135,4140,4171,4168,4169,4136],
            'Test2': [4146,4157,4151],
            'Test3': [4149,4161,4154],
            'Test4': [4148,4141,4159,4172,4153],
            'Test5': [4137,4147,4152,4158],
            'Test6': [4145,4155,4156,4146],
            'Test7': [4142,4173]
            }
        self._kst_mapping = kst_mapping
        
        
    def print_kst(self):
        print(self._kst_mapping[0])
```

When I execute `print_kst` I receive following error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

This indicates that the attribute has not being set correctly as it remains as None.

Do you have an idea what my mistake is?

Comment: Very likely because your property getter (or `set_kst_mapping()`) was not called before print_kst()

Comment: `print(self.kst_mapping)` - the `_` is not needed, and it's a dict, not a list.

Comment: @UltraInstinct yes this seems to be likely. But what is the prettiest waythat the function get called?

Comment: @bereal the ```_``` was the solution. After removing that it worked.

Comment: You should probably `print(self.kst_mapping)`.